# Function reference in java

Tags: java, function, pointers, reference

I want to have a reference to a function that isn't accepting any parametes and isn't return any result

```
public void myMethod()
{
    /*
     * My Code
     */
}
```

Comment: Wait.  What?  I have no idea what you're talking about.  For one thing, Java doesn't have pointers.

Comment: I mean to lambda. Java does have pointers to functions

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: Use a `Runnable`.

Comment: is it clearer??